# Replace Only Double Quotes Not Present Inside Other Double Quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

My issue is I have double quotes inside double quotes, but I only want to replace the quotes on the outside.

**Example**

```
{\"id\":\"apache \"obsolete\" version\",\"instances\":2}
```

Using `REPLACE({\"id\":\"apache \"obsolete\" version\",\"instances\":2}, '\"', '"')` doesn't work, as I end up with the below, which will break a JSON string.

```
{"id":"apache "obsolete" version","instances":2}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"id":"apache \"obsolete" version","instances":2}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your input is already broken? If it were a JSON snippet quoted in JSON it should be more like `{\"id\":\"apache \\\\\"obsolete\\\\\" version\",\"instances\":2}`, e.g.: `select * from openjson('{"foo": "{\"id\":\"apache \\\\\"obsolete\\\\\" version\",\"instances\":2}"}');`

Comment: Your initial string presumably is in double quotes. Your "expected output" contains double quotes (and escaped double quotes) so it must be enclosed in single quotes, which is equivalent to the double-quoted string `"{\"id\":\"apache \\\"obsolete\" version\",\"instances\":2}"`. `\\\"` is of course a backslash character followed by an escaped double quote.

Comment: Please make sure you represent that code as it really is. It makes no sense to have `REPLACE({` -- the first argument should be a string and cannot start with `{`. It is a syntax error. With this subject of replacing quotes it is of critical importance you represent the syntax concerning quotes *exactly* as it is, including backslashes that are escapes and not literal backslashes in a string literal. As you have represented it your JSON is not valid JSON. Provide code we can copy paste as query and execute and see the result.

Comment: Secondly, why in the expected result the quote after *obsolete* is not to be escaped? This question needs to be updated & corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to need to preserve *just* the escaped quote that's preceded by a space, so validity of your json string not withstanding, provided that's consistent with your data you can perform a nested replace that first targets that and excludes it from the global replace of escaped quotes and then restore it to get your desired result:

```
select Replace(Replace(Replace('{\"id\":\"apache \"obsolete\" version\",\"instances\":2}',' \"','~'),'\"','"'),'~',' \"');
```

> `{"id":"apache \"obsolete" version","instances":2}`